# How to make a function for button onclick option from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, button, popup

This is the javascript for ajax html popup

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.ajax-popup-link').magnificPopup({
        type: 'ajax',
        overflowY: 'scroll',
        closeOnContentClick: false
    });

});</script>
```

This is the button code

```
<input id="btn" type="button" value="click" onclick="myFunction();"/>
```

I have a popup html file name test.html which i need to open as popup on button click

Comment: what is `myFunction()` ?

Comment: i need to make a function myfunction() just a refrence name

Comment: Tie your ajax code to myFunction() like: function myFunction(){ // your code }

Answer (score 0):

Tie your ajax code to `myFunction()` like:

```
function myFunction(){ 
// your code 
$('.ajax-popup-link').magnificPopup({
    type: 'ajax',
    overflowY: 'scroll',
    closeOnContentClick: false

});
}
```

or remove the onclick from html input and add this to your script

```
$( "#btn" ).click(function() {
 $('.ajax-popup-link').magnificPopup({
    type: 'ajax',
    overflowY: 'scroll',
    closeOnContentClick: false
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Even better would be:

```
<input id="btn" type="button" value="click" />

function myFunction() {
  $('.ajax-popup-link').magnificPopup({
    type: 'ajax',
    overflowY: 'scroll',
    closeOnContentClick: false
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn").click(myFunction);
});
```

Now you do not have to `clutter' your HTML with JavaScript.

Comment: then how would i use the button to open popup

Comment: Now, when you click on the button, myFunction is executed.